# Query XML node with namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My goal is to be able to retrieve the value of `<Cdtr><Id>` from this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:com.firmaname:response.002">
    <DocId>1261076951</DocId>
    <CreateDtTm>2016-11-23T14:53:23.938Z</CreateDtTm>
    <ResponseCd>OK</ResponseCd>
    <Dbtr>
        <Id>debtorId</Id>
        <Name>debtorName</Name>
    </Dbtr>
    <Cdtr>
        <Id>creditorId</Id>
        <Name>creditorName</Name>
    </Cdtr>
</Document>
```

Note that this file 2 `<Id>` nodes, so I must specify the exact path to the node. The result should be 'creditorId'.

My code is:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:com.firmaname:response.002";
var results = requestMessage.Descendants(ns + "Id").First().Value;
```

But this will return 'debtorId'. I've searched here to find a way to retrieve an exact path, but they all seem to involve using Xpath with XElement. When using XElement I run into trouble with the namespace. All of the suggestions I find are about using XDocument...

Comment: Well, what do you wait when you call `First()`? Exactly, you wait the first matched item... So if you want to get id node tha has value `creditorId` just iterate all id nodes and retrieve `creditorId` from them or set filter in the `First(Func<T,bool>)`

Answer (score 0):

I would still use `XDocument` and select the `Cdtr` node, then the `Id` node within it.

One hack you can do with namespaces if you are confident you don't need them is to use `<element>.Name.LocalName`.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("<path to xml");

XNamespace ns = "urn:com.firmaname:response.002";

var creditorid = doc.Descendants().Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name == ns + "Cdtr").Elements()
    .First(e => e.Name == ns + "Id");
```

> Update using LocalName

```
var creditorid = doc.Descendants().Elements()
    .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Cdtr").Elements()
    .First(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Id");
```

This works, however you should use the namespace if you can.

Comment: I can't hardcode the path. Is there no way to provide a path as a parameter? Also, how would I use the LocalName with this?

Comment: By "path" do you mean "Cdtr"? Yes you can use a string variable there. If you mean the path to the xml then just load the XDocument however you want, that is just what I did to test my code. See Edit for using LocalName.

Comment: @Yoav can you explain how do you want to retrieve value? You want to retrieve value from id nodes or want to set full path to node in xml?

Comment: Just realised that SO was hiding part of the question so I edited the question, I am trying to retrieve the value of <Cdtr><Id>. But as someone said, this is just an example. In another case I may need <Cdtr><Name>, so can't hardcode <Cdtr><Id>. I ma also need to retrieve <Cdtr><Id>. The code should support either.

Comment: @Yoav do you want to get some node from <Cdtr><someChildNode> or **<Cdtr>** also can be specified by input argument?

Comment: The xml file is just an example. I am dealing with files with many more tags. The code should be able to receive a path to any node, and return the value. The issue is that the names of some of the nodes (like 'Id') repeat so I need to use a full path.